# How to convert Curl to url with headers

Tags: http, url, curl

I have this command in cURL and it works

curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API_KEY" \
  -G \      https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/Books

I want create a url that will execute the same way on the browser.
The website that I'm working with is back4app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve the same thing with just a URL. This relies on HTTP Headers (both `-H` parameters) that can't be translated to something else easily. To set these headers in a web browser, you'd at least need to execute JavaScript.

There *might* be a way if the target API supports reading the same fields from the url in some way (technically, there's no reason not to do this). I haven't found something on that topic in their docs, though.